# Applying index in r

Tags: r, indexing

I have data indexed. I'd like the first value in the index to be applied to the all the other values in that index. Below is an example I made.

```
index<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3)
animal<-c("cat","dog","lion","chicken","frog","goat","sheep","elephant","tiger", "bear")
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(index,animal))

index   animal
1      1      cat
2      1      dog
3      1     lion
4      2  chicken
5      2     frog
6      2     goat
7      2    sheep
8      2 elephant
9      3    tiger
10     3     bear
```

Result should look like:

```
index   animal
1      1      cat
2      1      cat
3      1      cat
4      2  chicken
5      2  chicken
6      2  chicken
7      2  chicken
8      2  chicken
9      3    tiger
10     3    tiger
```

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(index) %>% mutate(animal = first(animal))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option

```
df$animal <- with(df, animal[cummax(seq_along(index) * !duplicated(index))])
```